# Reading pdf books on my phone

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-nexus, pdf, ebooks

When I want to get/download books from Google Play Store, I usually get this notification:

[image]

But then I am not sure what to do afterwards to be able to read those pdf books on my phone. I've installed to ebook reader apps (kindle and another one), I also downloaded Google Play books app but I can't find those books exploring in those ebook reader apps and I can't find Google Play Books app on my phone to check whether it is possible to read them there.

Comment: What do you mean '*..downloaded Google Play books app..*' and '*..can't find Google Play Books app on my phone..*'?

Comment: @Sid: [This one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books&hl=en) and by the latter I meant I can't find it among the installed apps on my phone.

Comment: Actually I am looking for an elegant way of reading those books I find in the Google Play store on my phone!

Comment: you should have the icon in your app drawer. (search through every page carefully) If not, go to your play store app and search to find it. then try uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

Comment: @Sid: And then those books will be available from the app?

Comment: Yes. it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the Google Play Books app from the market ([link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books&hl=en))

If there is a problem with your installed app, open the app using Play Store app and uninstall and reinstall it. Now you should have the app shortcut in your app drawer.

In this app, you will be able to view your purchased books.

Comment: The app will show up as a blue book icon with the label "Play Books" (so you'll find it with the apps starting with "P" if your launcher sorts them alphabetically). Additionally if you're on a PC you can browse to http://books.google.com/  and (once you're logged in) you can click the My Library link (near the bottom of the page) to view and read books you've purchased in the Google Play store.

Comment: @GAThrawn: Yes, I knew what it looks like. Thank you. I can only read those book online, right?

Comment: @Gigili to read offline, you have to [make them available offline](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188708) and some books may nit be available for offline reading ([info](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs&ki_topic=28731&rd=1))